# how to remove time stamp or get only date form datepicker in flutter default datepicker?

Tags: android, flutter, datepicker

I am trying to get date from default datepicker widget of flutter but when i select date i get time with it.
I only want date not time. & would also like to change date format if possible.

This is what i have used from example somewhere.

```
DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2019),
        lastDate: DateTime(2020));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
  }
```

This is where I am getting value to string.
It prints like "2019-04-16 12:18:06.018950"

```
child: FlatButton(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        onPressed: () {
                          _selectDate(context);
                          print("Selected Date = $selectedDate");
                        },
                        child: Text(selectedDate == null
                            ? "Select Date"
                            : selectedDate.toString()),
                      )),
```

I want **only date** from this "2019-04-16 12:18:06.018950" and also change the format of date displaying like **"dd-mm-yyyy"**

is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I make the Custom DateFormat you can use this code then you will get the Output as :
16-04-2019

```
TextEditingController _datecontroller = new TextEditingController();

var myFormat = DateFormat('d-MM-yyyy');

Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: date,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    setState(() {
      date = picked ?? date;
    });
  }
```

and Inkwell widget goes like this

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
  child: IgnorePointer(
    child: TextField(
      controller: _datecontroller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(

        hintText: ('${myFormat.format(date)}'),
      ),

    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works perfectly... Btw I can do same for the time ri8?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `DateTime` class for that.
Simply parse your String and access individual parts as a property.

```
var date = DateTime.parse("2019-04-16 12:18:06.018950");
var formattedDate = "${date.day}-${date.month}-${date.year}";

print (formattedDate);
```

This will output

```
16-4-2019
```

Here's the official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html).

Comment: It worked but still I had to do some work around... Any way it works thanx

Comment: If I select Jan 1st, date.day gives value as '1', How can I get '01'?
is there any simple way to get then to check the value and add 0 at the start?

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `DateFormat` class from [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DateTime.now());
```

More details [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

There's also an option to use `DateTime.copyWith()`:

```
DateTime.now().copyWith(hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0, microsecond: 0);
```