# How to remove time from date flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to remove the time format from this date in a flutter,
I want to show a date like this `22-10-2019` or `2019-10-22`

```
2019-10-22 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55702290/7924072

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try below code:-

First you can create below method:-

```
String convertDateTimeDisplay(String date) {
    final DateFormat displayFormater = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS');
    final DateFormat serverFormater = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    final DateTime displayDate = displayFormater.parse(date);
    final String formatted = serverFormater.format(displayDate);
    return formatted;
  }
```

Second you can call above method like below code:-

```
  String yourDate = '2019-10-22 00:00:00.000';
  convertDateTimeDisplay(yourDate);
```

Answer (score 39):

There is now a [`DateUtils`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DateUtils-class.html) class that will handle this, using [`DateUtils.dateOnly`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DateUtils/dateOnly.html) :

```
DateUtils.dateOnly(date);
```

under the covers it is just using `DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day)` but it reads much better.

Note that it automatically sets date as local regardless of the input, there doesn't seem to be a way to force it to UTC :-(

Comment: Saved lot of time!

Answer (score 16):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.parse("2019-10-22 00:00:00.000");

var formate1 = "${dateTime.day}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.year}";

var formate2 = "${dateTime.year}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.day}";

print (formate1);
print (formate2);
```

OutPut will be :-

```
22-10-2019

2019-10-22
```

Comment: is the date in format is the same as dateTime ?

Comment: Use variable dateTime  instead of date.                                                                       
                                                                                                                                     
 var dateTime = DateTime.parse("2021-09-27 00:00:00.000");

var formate1 = "${dateTime .day}-${dateTime .month}-${dateTime .year}";

var formate2 = "${dateTime .year}-${dateTime .month}-${dateTime .day}";

print (formate1);
print (formate2);

Comment: Answer updated @KamauMbûgua

Answer (score 7):

To reformat your date you should use below method.

```
String convertedDate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format({your date object});
```

But if you have date string, so first you need to convert it to date object.

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse('2019-10-22 00:00:00.000');
```

and then,

```
String convertedDate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone needs to get only date from the current date then use the below code

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now(); 
DateTime onlyDate = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
```

Answer (score 3):

Add [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) dart package into your project.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Text( DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(DATE) // replace date with your data
```

https://youtu.be/VPuUoGzSJ5I

Comment: Awesome and simple to implement