# In Flutter i got a DateTime [yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000] how can i transfer that to be [yyyy-MM-dd] only?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, tostring, formatted

here is the code which i already formatted it to be [yyyy-MM-dd] but it also contains 00:00:00 :

```
    child: Text(
         _selectedDate == null
     ? 'No Date Choosen!'
     : '${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_selectedDate)}',
     style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),),
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702224, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new DateFormat object.

```
final df = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
Text(_selectedDate == null ? 'No Date Choosen!' : '${df.format(_selectedDate)}');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how formatting a date:

```
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
  print(formatted);
```