# how to remove time stamp and get only date from datepicker in flutter default datepicker widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get date from default datepicker widget of flutter but when i select date i get time with it. I only want date not time.

Here is my code:

```html
  TextEditingController dateCtl = TextEditingController();


CustomFromField(
                          heading: getTranslated(context, "date_sample"),
                          controller:dateCtl,
                          onTap: () async{
                            DateTime date = DateTime.now();
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                            final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
                                context: context,
                                initialDate:date,
                                firstDate:DateTime(1900),
                                lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                             
                          dateCtl.text = date.toIso8601String();
                            },
                        ),
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove time stamp or get only date form datepicker in flutter default datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702224/how-to-remove-time-stamp-or-get-only-date-form-datepicker-in-flutter-default-dat)

Answer (score 0):

This could help you

```
var date = DateTime.parse(picked.toString());

//this helps you to get your date only
var formatted = "${date.year}-${date.month}-${date.day}";
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated...

i just find a package that can do that for you
check out the package... it will help you.....
[age link](https://pub.dev/packages/age)

Comment: that did not helped

Comment: check the link of the package